# What is the proper "RESTFUL" way to list all posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I  am trying to figure out the proper restful way of displaying all posts from all users.

I have an application with a user and post resource. The post resource is nested in the users. Now I am trying to sort of display a feed of all posts and with the name of the user who posted them.

I cant quite figure out where this feed should be placed. And in view file, how to get post user names.

Comment: what do you mean with feed? view file?

Comment: Just for clarification purposes. I have a blog with many authors and each author can create posts. I have successfully created this association. Now all i want to do is display all the posts in the blogging application along with the author below each post. Displaying the posts is easy enough but trying to display the authors name as well is proving a challenge.

Comment: Even though you got an answer, you might want to reword the question title and first sentence in the question. [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is a style of software architecture. Though Rails states that its controllers can provide "RESTful" services and defines things as "RESTful resources" (such as in routes), it is up to the developer to understand the intent of REST. Some of the answers provided below are "REST-ish" imo, which is how many define Rails controllers, but calling them RESTful is not completely accurate.

Comment: To clarify, among other things, a strict interpretation of REST involves a self-describing API, so if you really define user and post as two separate resources, then you should not include users with posts. Instead, you would include URIs in the response to GET Posts that link to the User that posted the Post. If username should be a part of the definition of Post (resource), make it appear that way as far as the implementation goes for the PostsController (regardless of how you implement that). However, you don't have to do "proper" REST to implement a practical Rails controller.

Answer (score 1):

in controller:

```
@posts = Post.all(:include => "user")
```

in view:

```
<%  @posts.each do |post| %>
   ...
   some html here
   ...
   <%= post.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Pay attention to "include" word. It means that users information will be got with posts with 1 query to Database.
To better understand it you can read [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and currently getting this error - 
Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?-
Which controller exactly are you suggesting i define @posts ?

Comment: Just for clarification purposes. I have a blog with many authors and each author can create posts. I have successfully created this association. Now all i want to do is display all the posts in the blogging application along with the author below each post. Displaying the posts is easy enough but trying to display the authors name as well is proving a challenge.

Comment: Sorry, i've really misspelled. If post has one user you should write ":include => "user". I edited post.

You should put controller logic in index action of posts_controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route for displaying all posts by:

routes.rb

```
get "posts" => "posts#index"
```

This will create a route http://yourdomain.com/posts that will show all posts.  Then make sure you have an action for index to show all of the posts.

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all(:include => "user")
  end
end
```

Make sure your model associations are set up properly.

user.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
# This assumes you have a column on your table for user_id which I assume you do since you mentioned your nested resource already.
```

You view would simply show the user's name associated with each post.
views/posts/index.rb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  post.user.name
<% end %>
```

Comment: it's not a good advise! You should do @posts = Post.all(:include => "users") otherwise there would be many requests to Database ( equal to number of posts)